# Increase the timeout of one time OTP in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using speakeasy library to generate one time OTP  https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy

```
var token = speakeasy.totp({
            secret: secret.base32,
            encoding: 'base32',
            step:300
        });

        console.log(token);

        var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
            secret: secret.base32,
            encoding: 'base32',
            token: token
        });
        console.log(verified);
```

But when i add the `step` parameter value to 300 (expire token after 5 minutes)i will get `false` on `console.log(verified)`

So whats the correct way to increase the token expiration time?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the [time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy#getting-a-time-based-token-for-a-custom-time) option. With the [time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy#getting-a-time-based-token-for-a-custom-time) option, you can get a time-based token for a custom time.

```
var token = speakeasy.totp({
  secret: secret.base32,
  encoding: 'base32',
  time: 1453667708 // specified in seconds 
});
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Have you given the proper timestamp in `time`? The timestamp in this example is old.

Comment: `time:300` is my value (5minute)

Comment: `time` accepts a value in milliseconds. It's an [epoch](https://www.epochconverter.com/) time. So, 300 is not a valid number. Can you try setting `time: 1523953511` and let me know whether it works?

Comment: wait Let me try it